# objects in tilemap that uses spritebatch

Tags: love2d

So I use a spritebatch for my tiles. I have a ground layer, object layer, and foreground layer. The ground layer and foreground layer use 1 (and the same) spritebatch that uses 1 tilesheet of scenery tiles. The object layer is for actors and obviously use a different tilesheet. The drawing order is ground, object, foreground. So if I have 1 spritebatch for the scenery and 1 for the actors I don't see how can I get this draw order seeing as I would draw the 1 spritebatch for ground and foreground together with no way to put the object spritebatch between it since it's drawn with 1 command:

```
love.graphics.draw(tilesetBatch);
```

Comment: Why not just use separate sprite batches for the ground and foreground?

Answer (score 0):

For layers to work you will need two separate sprite batches.
i.e you need separate groundlayer and foregroundlayer spritebatchs.

```
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(groundlayer)
    love.graphics.draw(objectslayer)
    love.graphics.draw(foregroundlayer)
    ...
end
```